# Why all my wordpress sites keeps telling me that everything is up to date at /wp-admin/update-core.php?

Tags: plugins, themes, updates

Everything is in the title. I can't update my theme, plugins and wordpress, because wordpress tells me that everything is up to date.
On every single one of my sites (and there's a lot).

Comment: Do you have memcached, W3 Total Cache or apc plugin installed? If so disable them and try to update the plugin manually

Comment: how do you try to update wp-cli?

Comment: I had wp-rocket installed but it's disabled now and still not working. I'm simply trying via the the admin console Dashbord > Updates